# Even after incorporating " linespace = 'None' " in my code, the lines joining up points on graph have not gone away

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, line

Trying to rid my graph of the lines that join up the points in order to use my own line of best fit. I have used linespace='None' within my code for plotting the points. Very confused as to why the lines are still there after running the code again.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
x_a = np.array(x)    #defining x and y variables
y_a = np.array(y)

plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr = data)     #plotting  errorbars

plt.plot(x,y, ls='')      #plotting x and y. Attempting to get rid of lines with ls=''

plt.show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines are still coming from the `plt.errorbar`. Use `ls=''` for both

```
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=data, ls='')
plt.plot(x,y, ls='')
```

As pointed out by @DavidG in the comments, `plt.plot(x,y, ls='')` serves no purpose if you hide the lines. Instead, you can use a scatter plot in addition to the errorbar to show data points as

```
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, indeed. It is redundant here

Comment: @DavidG and Sheldore, thank you so much! It is all perfectly clear